# How can I draw the following figure in opengl?

Tags: opengl

I need to draw the following figure in openGL.

[image]

I tried to do that with polygons like this

```
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(9.5f,0,-20);
glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(20,0,-20);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);glVertex3f(20,0,40);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(9.5f,0,40);



glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(9.5f,0,40);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(-20,0,40);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);glVertex3f(-20,0,0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(-3.5f,0,0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);glVertex3f(9.5f,0,0);
```

I didn't get the exact figure, I got the following figure:

[image]

can anyone help??

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of what you get?

Comment: Also, if you're dealing with 2D I'd recommend changing things around so that +Z is 'up' and the X/Y axes work as one might expect.  I don't know about you but I find it far easier to think in the XY plane than in the XZ :)

Comment: @genpfault: Or just use `gluOrtho2D()`. `;]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Triangulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) your input polygon and render the resulting triangles.  [`GL_POLYGON`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBegin.xml) only works on convex polygons.

Alternatively you can use the [stencil buffer](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name13) to render concave polygons.

Comment: This is probably the only few solutions that is the most practical. I would triangulate as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll go with stencil buffer.

Comment: Please, can you help here
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823584/opengl-stencil-buffer-problem-wall-window