# OpenGl: Stencil buffer problem (Wall + Window)?

Tags: opengl, stencil-buffer

I want to create a wall with a window inside, using stencil buffer.
My code looks like this:

```
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glClearStencil(0);
glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
glStencilMask(1);
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 1);

glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);   
glColor3f(1,1,1);

//Window
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3d(-5,0,-20);
glVertex3d(-5,0,40);
glVertex3d(-20,0,40);
glVertex3d(-20,0,-20);
glEnd();

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, 1);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);

glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);                       
glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE0, eqr);   
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[1]);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glNormal3f(0.0f,-1.0,0.0f);

//Wall
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3d(20,0,-20);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3d(20,0,40);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3d(-20,0,40);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3d(-20,0,-20);

glEnd();
glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

But that doesn't work out, I got the whole fill wall without the window in it, any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you request an OpenGL context with a stencil buffer from your windowing system.  You may not get one by default unless you specifically ask for it.

Here's an [example](http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/dinoshade.c) using [GLUT](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/).  You'll want to look at the `glutInitDisplayMode()` call.

Here's another [example](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=26) using raw Win32.  The `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` bit is the important part.

[`glXChooseVisual()`](http://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/glXChooseVisual.html) is probably where you want to look if you're using X11.

I'd recommend [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_GLattr) if you want cross-platform context management.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your code, but I think that you should change

```
glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, 1);
```

to

```
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 1);
```